# How to render an image based on sent props?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am new to react and currently trying to practice a little bit. I have made one component called 'Recensie', and I render a couple of them in my  component.

Within this review component I would like to display an image, based on the image prop I sent from the  component. However I cannot get it to work. Currently this is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
function Recensie(props){
    return(
        <div className="recensie">
            {console.log(props.image)}
            <img src={`../imgs/${props.name}.png`}></img>
            <hr/>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Recensie
```

Where the main components code is like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import Recensie from './Recensie'

class Main extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={

        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="recensies">
                <Recensie name="one"/>
                <Recensie />
                <Recensie />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Main
```

However, the image does not actually show up:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm3GT.png

I have seen that I can import the exact image like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import imgs from '../imgs/one.png'

function Recensie(props){
    return(
        <div className="recensie">
            {console.log(props.image)}
            <img src={imgs}></img>
            <hr/>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Recensie
```

However, this would mean I have to hardcode the image.

Is there any way that I could do what I originally wanted to do, or is there a workaround I have to do?

Comment: You would have to use a dynamic import. The `Recensie` component would have to do an async require for the image based on the `name` passed to it. See here for more info https://codeburst.io/dynamic-imports-react-and-redux-29f6d2d88d77

Comment: Could you try someting like this ?
<img src={require(\`../imgs/${props.name}.png\`)} />

Comment: Hi, you need to reference an URL where the image can be found. With ` <img src={\`../imgs/${props.name}.png\`}></img>` I think you're trying to reference an image relatively to the directory of your .js file, but that is not how this works. You need to make sure your server serves the image file and reference it properly

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest example I could come up with:

```
class Recensie extends React.Component {
    state = {
        image: null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        import("./images/" + this.props.name).then((image) => {
            this.setState({ image: image.default });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.image ? (
            <img alt="image" src={this.state.image} />
        ) : null;
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
<Recensie name="test.png" />
```

It uses a dynamic import, which is asynchronous (async calls for data should be made in `componentDidMount`, see React docs for more info).

Don't forget to adjust the path to your images folder correctly, based on where the `Recensie` component is located.

Comment: This works, thank you very much, I am a bit confused about one particular part though, why is it that we say image:image.default instead of just image? What does .default do?

Comment: That's because webpack imports the module as a whole in this case, it takes all exports from it. By using the default property, you're receiving the default export, which in case of an image is the image. If it was a Javascript module, you could access all the exports using the dot syntax. An image "module" has only one export - the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way. Create file imageLoader.js inside some utils folder

```
// imageLoader.js
// inside images object i name routes for my images from assets folder
// and export loadImage function

const images = {
  img1: require('../../assets/images/img1.jpg'),
  img2: require('../../assets/images/img2.png'),
  flagNotFound: require('../../assets/images/flag_not_found.png')
};

export function loadImage(imageName) {
  if (images.hasOwnProperty(imageName)) {
    return images[imageName];
  }
  return images['flagNotFound'];
}
```

Use it like

```
import {loadImage} from '../location-to-imageLoader'

<img alt="not found" src={loadImage('img1')}/>
```

In your case

```
 <img alt="not found" src={loadImage(props.name)}/>
```